# If $f:U\rightarrow R$ is differentiable, $U\subset R^2$, and graph(f) is a regular surface, why is?

Tags: differential-geometry

> If $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\operatorname{graph}(f)=:S$ is a regular surface,  why is ?
>
> $1+||\nabla  f||^2=||f_x||^2||f_y||^2-2\langle f_x,f_y\rangle^2$

The original Question was to prove that;

$\operatorname{Area}(S)=\int_U\sqrt{1+|| \nabla f||^2}$

but in the lecture, we've seen that the area is $\int_U \det(g_{ij})^{1/2}$, where $(g_{ij})$ is the First Fundamental Form, So this is exactly the RHS of the equation.

Edit: Thank you very very much Fantini.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly it is that you're asking, and how the quote-box relates to what follows? Also, I'm confused by the notation of the RHS of the quote-box equation. If $f$ is scalar-valued, then so are its partials.

Comment: @JonathanY. Sorry for that, but Fantini already has corrected my fault in his answer. Actually it must be the graph of the function,r and not f (on the RHS of the quote-box)

Comment: @derivative I'm glad this helped you clear up confusions. :) Best wishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphs of functions have a parametrization given by

$$\mathbf{r}(x,y) = (x,y,f(x,y)).$$

The area of a surface is defined as

$$\operatorname{Area}(S) = \iint\limits_{R} \left\vert \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial y} \right\vert \, dA,$$

where $R$ is the projected region in the plane. Once you compute that you will find

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial y} = ( - f_x, - f_y, 1 ),$$

therefore

$$\left\vert \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial y} \right\vert^2 = 1 + (f_x)^2 + (f_y)^2 = 1 + ||\nabla f||^2.$$

This is the usual calculus way of doing it. Using differential geometry you need to compute $\sqrt{EG - F^2}$, where $E, G$ and $F$ are defined by

$$
\begin{align}
E & = \langle \mathbf{r}_x, \mathbf{r}_x \rangle, \\
G & = \langle \mathbf{r}_y, \mathbf{r}_y \rangle, \\
F & = \langle \mathbf{r}_x, \mathbf{r}_y \rangle.
\end{align}
$$

Notice that this is not equivalent to what you have written, because $\mathbf{r}_x \neq f_x$ and likewise for $y$. We have

$$\mathbf{r}_x = (1,0,f_x) \text{ and } \mathbf{r}_y = (0,1,f_y),$$

therefore

$$EG - F^2 = (1+f_x^2)(1+f_y^2) - (f_xf_y)^2 = 1+f_x^2 +f_y^2,$$

agreeing with the calculus definition, except that this is more general than for graphs.